Terraform fails to destroy Service Networking Connections
I am using terraform to create the infrastructure in GCP. When I do a terraform apply the infrastructure gets created successfully. I was also trying to delete the infrastructure but then the script fails to delete the service networking connection or VPC peering connection.
Error:
Unable to remove Service Networking Connection, err: Error waiting for Delete Service Networking Connection: Error code 9, message: Failed to delete connection; Producer services (e.g. CloudSQL, Cloud Memstore, etc.) are still using this connection.

If I manually delete the VPC peering connection and release the private IP everything works fine. And I am able to delete the infrastructure.
I am using GitHub Actions to delete the infrastructure. It simply executes the terraform destroy command
      - name: Terraform destroy
        working-directory: ${{ env.DIR }}
        run: terraform destroy -auto-approve

I have created separate modules for the VPC and Database.
VPC MODULE:
# Creating a custom VPC
resource "google_compute_network" "custom-vpc-network" {
  name                    = var.vpc_name
  project                 = var.project_id
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
  mtu                     = 1460
  routing_mode            = var.route_mode
  description = "Custom VPC for an ecommerce architecture"
}

# Creating a custom subnet
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "front-end-subnet" {
  ip_cidr_range            = var.ip_address_range_frontend
  region                   = var.project_region
  name                     = var.subnet_name_frontend
  network                  = google_compute_network.custom-vpc-network.name
  description = "subnet for frontend"
  private_ip_google_access = true
  stack_type               = var.stack_type
  log_config {
    aggregation_interval = var.aggregate_interval
    flow_sampling        = 0.5
    metadata             = var.include_all_metadata
  }
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "back-end-subnet" {
  ip_cidr_range            = var.ip_address_range_backend
  region                   = var.project_region
  name                     = var.subnet_name_backend
  network                  = google_compute_network.custom-vpc-network.name
  description = "subnet for backend"
  private_ip_google_access = true
  stack_type               = var.stack_type
  log_config {
    aggregation_interval = var.aggregate_interval
    flow_sampling        = 0.5
    metadata             = var.include_all_metadata
  }
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "database-subnet" {
  ip_cidr_range            = var.ip_address_range_database
  region                   = var.project_region
  name                     = var.subnet_name_database
  network                  = google_compute_network.custom-vpc-network.name
  description = "subnet for database"
  private_ip_google_access = true
  stack_type               = var.stack_type
  log_config {
    aggregation_interval = var.aggregate_interval
    flow_sampling        = 0.5
    metadata             = var.include_all_metadata
  }
}

DATABASE MODULE:
resource "google_compute_global_address" "private-ip-address" {
    name = var.private_ip_address
    address_type = var.private_ip_type
    purpose = var.private_ip_purpose
    network = var.network_id  
    prefix_length = 16
    depends_on = [ var.network_id ]
}

resource "google_service_networking_connection" "private-vpc-connection" {
    network = var.network_id
    service = var.service
    reserved_peering_ranges = [google_compute_global_address.private-ip-address.name]
    lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
    }
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "sql-instance" {
  name = var.sql_instance
  region = var.project_region
  database_version = var.database_version

  depends_on = [ google_service_networking_connection.private-vpc-connection ]

  settings {
    tier              = var.machine_type
    availability_type = var.availability_type_regional
    edition           = var.edition
    user_labels       = {
      environment = var.environment
    }
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled      = true
      private_network   = var.network_id
      enable_private_path_for_google_cloud_services = true
    }

    backup_configuration {
      enabled = true
      start_time = var.backup-time
      point_in_time_recovery_enabled = true
    }

    maintenance_window {
      day = 7
      hour = 20
      update_track = var.update_track
    }
  }
  deletion_protection = false
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database_instance" "sql-instance-read-replica" {
  name = "${var.sql_instance}-replica"
  master_instance_name = google_sql_database_instance.sql-instance.name
  region = var.project_region
  database_version = var.database_version

  settings {
    tier              = var.machine_type
    availability_type = var.availability_type_zonal
    edition           = var.edition
    user_labels       = {
      environment = var.environment
    }
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled      = true
      private_network   = var.network_id
      enable_private_path_for_google_cloud_services = true
    }
  }
  deletion_protection = false
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

}

resource "google_sql_database" "postgresql-database" {
    name = var.postgresql-database
    instance = google_sql_database_instance.sql-instance.name 
}

resource "google_sql_user" "postgresql-user" {
    name = var.db_username_output
    instance = google_sql_database_instance.sql-instance.name
    password = var.db_password_output
}   


I have already added depends on to make sure that terraform knows the order in which to delete the dependencies. If I add depends on to the VPC I would get into a circular dependency issues.
Please let me know on where I went wrong

The flag deletion_policy = "ABANDON" was introduced to avoid such errors https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/magic-modules/pull/9765

The issue you're facing is because the Cloud SQL instance still uses the service networking connection when you try to destroy it with Terraform.
Try removing depends_on from the google_sql_database_instance. This removes the circular dependency.

If I do that cloud sql is not able to recognize the service connection and I am getting the following error
╷
│ Error: Error, failed to create instance because the network doesn't have at least 1 private services connection. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#network_requirements for how to create this connection.
│
│   with module.database.google_sql_database_instance.sql-instance,
│   on ../../modules/database/main.tf line 19, in resource "google_sql_database_instance" "sql-instance":
│   19: resource "google_sql_database_instance" "sql-instance" {
